# Most likely transformation of an image

Tags: image-processing

A graylevel reference image is transformed displacing each pixel. The magnitude of the displacement follows a bidimensional gaussian distribution. When two pixels in the reference image fall in the same pixel in the transformed image, the resulting graylevel of the transformed image is the sum of graylevels of both pixels in the reference image.

Is it possible to calculate the most likely bidimensional gaussian distribution of the transformation? Do you know any research paper about it?

Comment: A few questions: **1)** Is the entire image translated uniformly, or is this a random pixel-by-pixel shift? **2)** Can any given pixel contribute to more than one pixel value in the transformed image? **3)** What exactly are you looking for? You have a reference image and a transformed image and you are trying to estimate the parameters of the bivariate gaussian distribution used in the transformation?

Comment: Hey, welcome to DSP.se! Your question seems to have (almost) enough information to be answered (you could add the info @nispio is asking about)... but, as this is a community website, you could try adding some context about the problem you're trying to solve. While some problems are interesting all on their own, most problems have a better chance of getting the communities interest if they give context and purpose to the problem.

Comment: Answering to @nispio: 1) It's a pixel-by-pixel shift 2) No, every pixel in the reference contributes only to one pixel of the transformed image 3) Yes, exactly this. Whit respect to the motivation of the question, I believed that knowing the parameters of the transformation could be very useful for 2D dosimetry in radiotherapy.